# rqt_graph crashes

Tags: ros, python, rqt-graph, rqt, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After  running
$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

i get the following error msg:

```
PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_graph/RosGraph#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 116, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 202, in restore_settings
    self._refresh_rosgraph()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 226, in _refresh_rosgraph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 259, in _update_graph_view
    self._redraw_graph_view()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 292, in _redraw_graph_view
    same_label_siblings=True)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/dot_to_qt.py", line 254, in dotcode_to_qt_items
    subgraph_nodeitem = self.getNodeItemForSubgraph(subgraph, highlight_level)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/dot_to_qt.py", line 83, in getNodeItemForSubgraph
    bb = subgraph.attr['bb'].strip('"').split(',')
KeyError: 'bb'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192782/rqt_graph-crashes/) by [Tomaszz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19879/tomaszz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-18**:
What version of these two packages do you use: rqt_graph and qt_dotgraph?
Also please provide more information since you are likely doing more than what you described. E.g. which packages did you try to visualize in the graph?

**Comment by [Tomaszz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19879/tomaszz/) on 2014-09-19**:
Well, I'm not sure what do  you mean by version of rqt_graph. I use ROS Indigo. Problems with rqt_graph started when using  VREP together with ROS. For the first time it crashed when I played the simulation on  VREP. Officially VREP doesn't support ROS Indigo. Now each rqt_graph run fails.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-19**:
With "version" I mean the version of the Debian package you have installed. Please run "dpkg -l | grep rqt-graph" and "dpkg -l | grep qt-dotgraph" and post the result. My second question was: which packages did you try to visualize in the graph?

**Comment by [Tomaszz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19879/tomaszz/) on 2014-09-20**:
1/ ros-indigo-rqt-graph   0.3.9-0trusty-20140905-0110-+0000 amd64
ros-indigo-qt-dotgraph  0.2.26-0trusty-20140819-0222-+0000  amd64

2/ i tried to visualize vrep tutorials packages "ros_bubble_rob", "vrep_joy" etc

actually now  it  works  fine :P I have restarted my laptop

**Comment by [Robopija](https://answers.ros.org/users/20313/robopija/) on 2014-09-26**:
I get exactly the same error message. I have ros-indigo-rqt-graph 0.3.9-0trusty-20140905-0309-+0000 i386 and ros-indigo-qt-dotgraph 0.2.26-0trusty-20140819-0326-+0000 i386, i don't use VREP. This happens even if no ros nodes are running, just a roscore.

**Comment by [VinceDietrich](https://answers.ros.org/users/14941/vincedietrich/) on 2015-02-19**:
I have the same problem. Restarting Ubuntu helps at first, but error came back. Installing  ros-indigo-qt-gui-app and ros-indigo-qt-gui-core did not help for me so far.

ros-indigo-rqt-graph  0.3.10-0trusty-20141230-0525-+0000 amd64
ros-indigo-qt-dotgraph 0.2.26-0trusty-20141230-0049-+0000 amd64

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-02-19**:
If anybody could come up with a minimal example to reproduce the issue it might be feasible to fix the problem.

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2015-02-26**:
Hello: I get the same problem. My versions are

ii  ros-indigo-rqt-graph    0.3.10-0trusty-20141230-0525-+0000    amd64

ii  ros-indigo-qt-dotgraph   0.2.26-0trusty-20141230-0049-+0000   amd64

and I am trying to use rqt_graph as on A Gentle Introduction to ROS (J.M. O'Kane) p24

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2015-02-26**:
(cont): rosnode list

lists

/rosout

/teleop_turtle

/turtlesim

Workaround/clue: I just found that unticking 'Hide Debug' clears the error and displays the graph. Ticking 'Hide Debug' gives the error message again.

**Comment by [gocarlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/21835/gocarlos/) on 2015-03-11**:
happen here too...
nothing open and still crashing. only two very small packages in the WS

**Comment by [silverArgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22165/silverargon/) on 2015-04-15**:
Hi, im having the same problem. Tried both install  ros-indigo-qt-gui-app and ros-indigo-qt-gui-core and restarting, but with no result. Any guess to what it could be?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-04-23**:
As before: if anybody could come up with a minimal example (using ROS packages) to reproduce the issue it might be feasible to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can vouch for Tomaszz, restarting Ubuntu after installing rqt_graph and plugins fixes this issue.

---

Originally posted by [DataCrusader21](https://answers.ros.org/users/20353/datacrusader21/) with karma: 16 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0